# Grandstream wp820 not registering after router/modem switch

Tags: voip, sip, ubiquiti, draytek

#### Greetings fellow system engineers!

I'm new to the forum and I do have a rather strange problem. Please be aware that I am encountering the following issue as a hobbyist / power-user. I do have some amount of knowledge but seemingly not enough. I am really frustrated right now because the change I made worked out great until I realised the problem (as it is always). Most likely I overlooked or didn't understand something correctly but I hope someone has a solution to my problem, encountered something similar or has a pointer in the right direction. So, here we go...

### What I have

A few days ago I finally bought a `Draytek Vigor 167` for my home network. I replaced my former `AVM FritzBox 7590` to bring down power usage, finally use IPv6 in its full glory and most importantly to eliminate the double NAT. Behind the modem I have a `Ubiquiti Dream Machine Pro` formerly running in DHCP behind the AVM router and now with PPPoE passthrough. All my other devices are connected to the `unifi network`. My ISP is `Telekom Germany`.

One of the devices inside the unifi network is a `Grandstream wp820` handheld IP-phone. While using the AVM router as the DSL modem it worked great after correct configuration. I bought it because I already have a good wifi coverage all over my house and I don't want to have another wireless standard (like DECT) inside the building.

Before:

```
Telekom DSL ==> AVM FritzBox 7590 ==> UDM-Pro (DHCP) ==(wifi)==> GS wp820
```

After:

```
Telekom DSL ==> Draytek Vigor 167 (modem-mode) ==> UDM-Pro (PPPoE) ==(wifi)==> GS wp820
```

### The Problem

The wp820 suddenly stopped working after I switched over to the Draytek modem. And exactly that is the problem: I didn't change anything within the configuration of the phone after switching over. Now it will just not register with my ISP although it worked just fine before and if I try to make an outbound call it will report `Call failed! No Response`.

### What I tried

As it should be (in my humble opinion) I did my homework. I spent nearly two whole days with research and t&e. But I wouldn't write here if it had worked out. The things I tried are not really in their timely order but I'll try to remember as much as I can.

- As far as the Telekom support could say there are no problems with my connection and modem synchronisation to the ISP servers. Also as already said: Internet works just fine.
- I tried disabling the ISP VLan configured inside the DrayTek modem and setting it for the WAN connection of the UDM-Pro.
- I tried to setup DNS servers delivered to my devices manually within the UDM-Pro to accomplish the goal of being able to ping `tel.t-online.de` (which is seemingly impossible anyway because SIP uses an even deeper sub-domain).
- I tried enabling (default was off) the SIP conntrack module inside the firewall-settings of the UDM-Pro and disabling all of them (I tested either way).
- I set up port-forwarding within the UDM-Pro which was seemingly pointless because this only gives an advantage for inbound or already established calls.
- I scoured forums, blog articled, videos a.s.o. to search for different configurations for the wp820. Most of the time I tried to match configurations of other GS phones to mine because there are very few good examples. I also tried exporting the configuration of the AVM router and tried to make sense of the information contained within the exported file but that didn't work out either.
- I reset the wp820 to eliminate the factor of a prior misconfiguration and configured ONLY WLAN, the basics of one SIP account, removed the default STUN server address and changed the transport method from UDP to TCP.

Configuration of the phone for ISP (I used [this guide](https://www.telekom.de/hilfe/werksreset-speedport/werksreset-faq/einrichtung-sip-client) as guidance):

[configuration of the phone for ISP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46Sqr.png)

- I created a separate network and VLan inside the UDM-Pro to separate the phone from any other devices.
- I set up the AVM router I used before as IP client (inside the separate VLan mentioned before) and tried using it as a base station. I was not able to get registration to work in that case either. I pinged the router from the phone and it worked so connectivity wasn't the issue. **Interestingly enough the FritzBox is able to connect all three configured phone numbers while in IP client mode and behind the UDM-Pro. So what am I missing in terms of configuration of the wp820??**

Configuration of the phone and AVM router:

[configuration of the phone and AVM router](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCwvq.png)

### What I want

So after this mess of t&e I just want it to work.

The best case scenario for me is that I can use the IP phone as it is intended to connect directly to my ISP utilising all of its potential. I do not mind and will probably keep the separate VLan for future devices of the same type (only if we get it to work).

I really don't want to adopt another technology like DECT.

I would also don't mind if I had to use the AVM router as a base station. This would open up the possibility to make internal calls but defeats the energy consumption benefits I pointed out at the beginning. (I know that I am running an UDM-Pro... But at least I'm trying)

---

I want to thank everyone in advance because it drives me crazy that this just doesn't work. If someone needs more screenshots or further info of my configuration I am happy to provide it. And although I'm only a hobbyist for that matter I used wireshark before and I am not shy of using other tools to debug this mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, some hours and a thoughtful shower later I found the solution and I feel kind of stupid about it. But nevertheless it feels important to share the answer and configuration to help you all out there.

Two things (which are essentially the same) from the original question played together to mess me up:

> [...] bring down power usage, **finally use IPv6 in its full glory** and most importantly to eliminate the double NAT.

> I reset the wp820 to **eliminate the factor of a prior misconfiguration** [...]

Maybe you already know what happened. Correct: IPv6 happened! As I configured the WLan of the wp820 (after resetting) it I set it (again) to `Both, Prefer IPv6` because I love that tech and wanted to use it on all of my devices. But seemingly my ISPs SIP servers don't support that or some DNS magic has gone wrong.

The solution was as simple as eating a cookie: setting my device to `IPv4 only`. I also tried `Both, Prefer IPv4` which works too but now that I'm burnt I'll try to avoid IPv6 for SIP with my ISP as much as I can.

#### Now to the configuration

Please do not yell at me if something does not work for you. I will try to assist if something does not work for you but the following settings are certainly working for me. I reset my phone again to factory defaults and configured it by changing **only the settings I stated below**. It worked instantly.

The reference for the german alternative names are directly provided by my ISPs documentation [found here](https://www.telekom.de/hilfe/werksreset-speedport/werksreset-faq/einrichtung-sip-client?samChecked=true).

`wp820 / Account / General Settings`

| option | german alt. name | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Account Name |  | Some name to identify your profile / phone number |
| SIP Server | Registrar | tel.t-online.de |
| SIP User ID | SIP-ID Benutzer | Your phone number in international format (+49...) without spaces and other symbols (i.e. `+4912345678910`) |
| SIP Authentication ID | Authentifizierungsname Benutzername | Your E-Mail address used to login to "Telekom Kundencenter" **OR** your "Zugangsnummer" (a multiple digit long number) found on the document initially received after ordering or within your "Kundencenter" |
| SIP Authentication Password |  | Your password used to login to "Telekom Kundencenter" |
| Display Name |  | Some display name to identify you at the other end of the line. (i.e. the phone number you're registering) |
| Tel URI |  | Disable |
| Outbound Proxy |  | tel.t-online.de |
| DNS Mode |  | SRV (NAPTR/SVR **does not work**! It registers but returns 403 (forbidden) when trying to make an outbound call) |
| DNS SRV Failover Mode |  | Default |
| NAT Traversal |  | Auto |

`wp820 / Account / SIP Settings`

Within here I left everything as default and changed only the values below. I will update the table if I need to adjust some registration times because I also had to do this before the router/modem swap. This was needed to make inbound calls work consistently. Sometimes it would show up as registered but inbound calls would fly away into the void. Making an outbound call refreshed the state but after some time it would happen again.

| option | value |
| --- | --- |
| SIP Transport | TCP |

`wp820 / Phone Settings / General Settings / Basic Settings`

| option | value |
| --- | --- |
| STUN Server | [empty] |

`wp820 / Network Settings / WiFi Settings / WiFi Basics`

| option | value |
| --- | --- |
| IP Mode | IPv4 Only **or** Both, Prefer IPv4 |

`wp820 / Network Settings / WiFi Settings / Advanced Settings`

| option | value |
| --- | --- |
| Country Code | Germany |

---

As I already stated multiple times: feel free to ask if something is still unclear.

I would really like to know if this rather short description saved someone's day. It would certainly have saved mine.

Answer (score 0):

Dear German contributor and owner/user of a Grandstream WP820 VoIP phone,

Your problem was somewhat different to mine, but common to both was that we had FRITZ!Boxes and telephone accounts with Telekom here in Germany (I'm writing this in Bremen). My problem was registering a SIP account for my recently acquired Grandstream WP822 VoIP phone. None of the How Tos or discussions I found in the internet that were concerned with making a Grandstream VoIP phone work with a FRITZ!Box were of any help. As naming "fritz.box" as the SIP server (and basing all other attendant entries in the Grandstream account General Settings form on the fact that the SIP server was a "fritz.box") was not working, I tried out your approach of basing my General Settings on my status as a Telekom customer.

Your table with German- and English-language columns was of great assistance. In particular, your instruction to enter the Telekom "Zugangsnummer" as the "Authenticate ID" was invaluable. I guessed that what Telekom call "Ihr persönliches Kennwort" was the entry needed for the "Authenticale Password" box, and this seems to be the case. At any rate I now have a SIP registration. What a relief after such a wearing struggle. So thank you very much indeed!

If there are other people having difficulties registering their Grandstream WP822, then they can go ahead and try out the method you describe for setting up a Grandstream WP820.

Kind regards,

Hugh McComb